# Mock private variables that are assigned in constructor

Tags: java

I have a constructor like so:

```
private final String secretKey;
private int size;

public implementationA(int size) {
   this.secretKey = Preconditions.checkNotNull(System.getenv("SECRET_KEY"), "some error");
   ... a few more assignments identical to this
   this.size = size;
}
```

I need to somehow set the assignment variables so I can instantiate this constructor during testing.
As it stands, the Precondition fails during testing, as my testing pipeline doesn't include env variables like this.

I was looking at using something like ReflectionTestUtils.setField, but that only seems to work after you have created the object. In my case, the object creation has an exception because one or more of the env vars are missing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you considered just setting that environent variable in whatever launch system runs your tests?

Answer (score 0):

you could use PowerMockito:

```
@Test
public void testImplementationAWithEnv() {
  String key = "testKey";
  PowerMockito.mockStatic(System.class);
  PowerMockito.when(System.getenv("SECRET_KEY")).thenReturn(key);
  ImplementationA impl = new ImplementationA(5);
}
```